# Plot dataset with X range in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a dataset containing an X range and Y values. Example:

```
X0 X1 Y 
0  1  0.1 
1  2  0.2 
2  3  0.3

QZSS L1CA 30 32 0.025 
QZSS L1CA 32 34 0.022 
QZSS L1CA 34 36 0.019 
QZSS L1CA 36 38 0.016 
QZSS L1CA 38 40 0.014 
QZSS L1CA 40 42 0.013
```

so I need to plot all the values without interpolation, how can I plot with the X range?
I have this code:

```
             j = 1;
                for i = 50-range:step:50
                    mask = ~isnan(ddcr) & (cno >= i) & (cno <= i+step);
                    x_cno(j) = i + step/2;
                    std_cr(j) = std((ddcr(mask)),'omitnan');
                    std_pr(j) = std((ddpr(mask)),'omitnan');
                    med_cr(j) = median(abs(ddcr(mask)));
                    med_pr(j) = median(abs(ddpr(mask)));
                    %%titleStr, i, i+step, std_cr(j), std_pr(j), med_cr(j), med_pr(j)
fprintf('%s %d %d %.3f %.3f %.3f %.3f\n',titleStr, i, i+step, std_cr(j), std_pr(j), med_cr(j), med_pr(j))




                    j = j + 1;
                end
```

i and i+step are the x range. First, the Omitnan doesn't work. Something wrong with it?
Second, how do I plot the X range and Y values without interpolations?

```
scatter(i+step,std_cr(j))
```

this is wrong. Any idea?

Comment: Please [edit] the question with a [mre], i.e. code that we can run. A few loose lines from what appears to be inside a loop doesn't tell us much.

Comment: `plot(X0, Y); hold on; plot(X1,Y);`. Otherwise I'm not sure what you're asking - you give a *very brief* table and jump directly into some code you haven't explained, with no data, and no representative code we can run.

Comment: ok more simple:
X0 X1 Y
0  1   0.12
1  2   0.14
2  3   0.16
3  4   0.18

How do you plot this in excel without interpolating? do you take just X1 as x axis?

Comment: Your question is confusing because you're giving two values for x. You ask `how can I plot with the X range?` but you have `X0` and `X1`. Can you define what the `X range` is?

Comment: This almost looks like you've got something more like a **slope** between two x-axis points and not really a y-axis value at a given x-axis point.

Comment: X range i am defining it is right X0 X1, so y value is contained between x0 x1.

Comment: "contained between x0 x1" - like, exactly in the middle? Interpolated somewhere else?

Comment: exactly : 30 32 0.025 , so value in the middle

Answer (score 1):

Still not clear what you've got going on, but if you're trying to plot the y values as if they're located exactly between the `X0` and `X1` values, then you can average those two values and then plot, like:

```
x_avg = X0 + 0.5*(X1-X0);
plot(x_avg, Y);
```

This gets something like:

[image: plotted figure using X0-X1 averaged values]

If you're thinking the `Y` values are a slope, then you need to numerically integrate that to recover the actual y values. You can do this by multiplying each `Y` value by the distance between corresponding `X0` and `X1` values, like:

```
x_deltas = X1 - X0;
y_deltas = Y.*x_deltas; % Note the element-wise .* operator, not just *
```

Then you need to assume some starting value and take the cumulative sum of the `y_deltas`:

```
starting_y = 0;
recovered_y = cumsum(y_deltas) + starting_y;
```

Now you can start the plot at `x0(1)` for the x-value and `starting_y` for the y-value, then can move on to `x1` for the remaining x-values and `recovered_y` for the remaining y-values:

```
plot([X0(1), x1], [starting_y, recovered_y])
```

Again the point here is to treat your y-values as **slopes** between the x0 and x1 values, which would give you a plot that looks like:

[image: plotted figure using y values as slopes between x0 and x1]

And here you can see that your x0-x1 deltas are 1 between each, and so if you choose `starting_y = 0`, at x0(1) you get `starting_y` which is zero, then at x1(1) you get the **slope** of 0.1 over that span of 1, which gives you 0.1 at x1(1). Then you take a slope of 0.2 over then next span of 1, which gives you a y-delta of 0.2, which builds on the previous value of 0.1, giving you y=0.3 at x1(2), etc.